# Text Form Twitter API?

Tags: json, api, parsing, twitter, format

I'm making a Twitter account statistics program that reads tweets, retweet counts, and favorite counts. I could attempt to read the user's Twitter account URL line by line and parse the information from there, but I was wondering if there was a public API or part of Twitter that just spits out the raw data without formatting it all pretty for web browsers? Not only would this be more efficient in the program, but would also be much neater.

It seems as though API 1.1 uses JSON to fetch data, but I need to make a developer account and create unique identifiers in order to access such data. Is it worth it? Is there some sort of alternative that would be faster and easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All API calls to Twitter now require OAuth authentication, so there is unfortunately no way around signing up for a developer account and creating an app. It's not even possible to use a service that makes the requests on your behalf, as this is re-syndication which is forbidden by Twitter's API terms, so you need to make the calls yourself.